# WPF wrapper for custom CEF nuget package

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I recompiled **CEF** with some `features enabled` and also successfully compiled it as **Nuget package**, as you can see below now I can browse my custom compiled **Cef_Binaries** (x64 only - target platform).

But I have no idea how to make WPF wrapper, so I can use this inside my project
(**Just like nuget package CEFSharp.WPF**)

Sorry if it's a silly question but after spending hours on compiling CEF, I'm brain-dead already

[image]

> Packages you are seeing above are my local compiled nuget packages

**Update #1:: I successfully made Nuget Package from my new CefSDK**

Repo:: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/98/

1. After running `UpdateNugetPackages.ps1`

   ```
   $CefVersion = '98.2.1'
   ```
2. I used this `build.ps1` to compile my NuGet packages with these params

   ```
   param(
   [ValidateSet("vs2022","vs2019", "nupkg-only", "update-build-version")]
   [Parameter(Position = 0)] 
   [string] $Target = "nupkg-only",
   [Parameter(Position = 1)]
   [string] $Version = "98.2.1",
   [Parameter(Position = 2)]
   [string] $AssemblyVersion = "98.2.1",
   [Parameter(Position = 3)]
   [ValidateSet("NetFramework", "NetCore", "NetFramework452", "NetCore31")]
   [string] $TargetFramework = "NetCore31",
   [Parameter(Position = 4)]
   [string] $BuildArches = "x64"
   )
   Set-StrictMode -version latest;
   $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
   ```

Comment: Are you planning on using the CefSharp.Wpf package? Or are you actually trying to write your own?

Comment: @amaitland Write my own... CefSharp.Wpf don't have codec support. I compiled CEF again with codec enabled and now want to wrap it somehow to use inside WPF project

Comment: You can compile CefSharp to use your custom build if you've created a custom cef.sdk package.  Creating your own wrapper is a massive task you'll have to research yourself.

Comment: To build CefSharp you can add your private Nuget repository to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/98/NuGet.config and change the version number and subsequently run https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/98/UpdateNugetPackages.ps1#L8 (script looks for Nuget.exe in parent folder). If you compiled CEF correctly then you should be able to build CefSharp. Use build.ps1 to compile and create Nuget packages.

Comment: @amaitland I was doing the exact same as you mentioned, somehow my compiled versions are not working, so I compiling it again... But really thanks for your assistance

Comment: Make sure you a creating an Official build, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/AutomatedBuildSetup.md#markdown-header-windows-configuration for the basic commands per arch, you can add your own custom settings from there.

Comment: @amaitland I am so close now! just having last issue i guess, I want to make it only for x64... when I export **nuget** `CEFSharp.WPF.NetCore` to my project I got this error

`Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file win-arm64\lib\netcoreapp3.1\Ijwhost.dll
Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file win-x86\lib\netcoreapp3.1\Ijwhost.dll" 
Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file win-x86\lib\netcoreapp3.1\CefSharp.dll" 
Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file runtimes\win-arm64\lib\netcoreapp3.1\CefSharp.dll"`

**I made this NUGET packages from `build.ps1` with `$BuildArches = "x64"`**

Comment: What are the exact arguments you used? Copy and paste of what you executed please

Comment: @amaitland please check new update#1 in question

Comment: Packages should be fine. Did you specify a `RuntimeIdentifier` as per the post install instructions? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/100/NuGet/PackageReference/Readme.txt#L10 As your only building x64 you'll need to specify `win-x64`.

Comment: @amaitland you are great sir! It's finally working now, one silly ques if I try **Debug-x64 & Run** I got error `libcef.dll.pdb` not found but if I do **Release-x64 & Run**, then it works smoothly

Comment: An error or a warning? I wouldn't expect the missing pdb to be an error. Just a warning which you can ignore, or you can copy the pdb from your source build of CEF.

Comment: It's triggering breakpoints and basically not running, but I will try as you suggested... thanks once again

Comment: CefSharp only ever packages release builds of CEF. Not sure what you've actually created packages for or what you compiled, so probably you've made a mistake somewhere.